# An MCQ about the median of a triangle.

Tags: geometry

There is an MCQ given in our book which is the following;
The point of intersection of the medians of a triangle devids them in the ratio:

$1)$ $1:2$

$2)$ $2:1$

$3)$ $1:3$

$4)$ $4:1$
I can choose both $1)$ and $2)$ because they are the same things. Am I correct?

Comment: It depend on the part you are taking in the numerator and denominator.

Answer (score 1):

If I must select one out of the given four, I will choose 2:1. This is because, from http://www.mathopenref.com/trianglemedians.html, “A median of a triangle is a line segment from a vertex of the triangle to the midpoint of the side opposite that vertex”. For a median, counting starts from the vertex, then the centroid, and finally the midpoint of the side opposite that vertex.

However, this type of guessing MCQ is not recommended because precise description (with fuller details to avoid ambiguities) is usually required in a mathematical statement.

Answer (score 0):

It's $2:1$ not $1:2$.The upper portion is $2x$ and lower is $x$.Generally it is written in the form $2:1$.

Comment: If you draw the triangle upside down then the upper portion is half the lower. There is absolutely no indication why we should favor the longer part over the shorter one when we take the ratio.

Comment: @Wojowu-I said **generally**...we do not **generally** draw a triangle upside down...:-)

Comment: Generally we draw a triangle with at least _one_ of its medians "upside down".

Comment: @DavidK-https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_(geometry).Refer to the figure.